# How does `update-alternatives --config somecommand` find the symlinks for `somecommand`?

Tags: software-installation, path, alternatives

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/48374564/156458

> `update-alternatives --config java` works by installing symlinks to commands as `/usr/bin/java`,  `/usr/bin/javac` and so on.

How does `update-alternatives --config somecommand` find the symlinks for `somecommand`?

For example, does it rely on `$PATH`, and therefore work in the same way as how bash find the files for `somecommand` when running `somecommand` directly in bash?

If the file for `somecommand` is not a symlink, will `update-alternative --config somecommand` work?

Thanks.

Comment: I usually (ab)use  `ltrace` and `strace` for those quick doubts.

Comment: Or, list the contents of the package that provides the command/binary, and traverse the directories and read its manpage(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way `update-alternatives` works is described in its [manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/dpkg/update-alternatives.1). The list of available alternatives for a given command (or file, in general — alternatives aren’t limited to commands) is stored in a file in `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives` on Debian and derivatives; thus the alternatives for `java` are stored in `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/java`. On Fedora, RHEL, and derivatives, the files are stored in `/var/lib/alternatives`.

When a package wishes to provide an alternative, it installs it using `update-alternatives --install` (and appropriate parameters); when it wishes to remove an alternative, it does so using `update-alternatives --remove`. You can use these to provide your own alternatives if necessary.

Note that in Java’s case specifically, on Debian and derivatives, the alternatives handling is a little more complex and you should use `update-java-alternatives` instead of manipulating all the alternatives manually.

If for some reason an alternative-managed file is not a symlink, `update-alternatives` will consider that the alternative is broken and will refuse to touch it.

Comment: Interesting note about java alternatives there.  I'm not at all familiar with how or why that would be the case, however using `update-alternatives` has always worked for me when dealing with java.  Additionally, while the original work was created by debian developers, RedHat-based distros have adapted it as well.  Although, there is no specific `update-java-alternatives` command on RHEL, e.g.  It might be worth noting as well, on RedHat-based systems, the path is `/var/lib/alternatives` for the alternative scripts.

Comment: @ILMostro_7 right, `update-alternatives` still works, `update-java-alternatives` makes it easier to update *all* the JRE/JDK-provided tools when changing JVMs (look at the `/var/lib/jvm/.*.jinfo` files for details). Thanks for the comment, I’ve updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks.  Why "in Java’s case specifically, on Debian and derivatives, the alternatives handling is a little more complex and you should use update-java-alternatives instead of manipulating all the alternatives manually" ?
I am reading https://askubuntu.com/questions/159575/how-do-i-make-java-default-to-a-manually-installed-jre-jdk, but still can't figure it out.

Comment: @Tim, for Java packages, there are lots of different alternatives, none of which are connected (partly because you might only have a sub-selection of the commands installed); so if you want to switch from Java 8 to Java 9 for example, you’d have to update a couple of dozen alternatives manually... `update-java-alternatives` does that for you.

Comment: What are " a couple of dozen alternatives" that I have to update manually? Is `$JAVA_HOME` included?

Comment: @Tim see my comment addressed to ILMostro_7 above for details. `$JAVA_HOME` isn’t a file, so it isn’t included (it can’t be managed using alternatives).

Comment: Thanks. https://askubuntu.com/a/521154/1471 seems to just use `update_alternatives` instead of `update_java_alternatives`, and I wonder if the way there is recommended?

Comment: @Tim, that answer explains how to install the Oracle JDK, and uses `update-alternatives` in the manual setup which doesn’t support `update-java-alternatives`. I wouldn’t recommend that approach.

Comment: Thanks. Could you describe or point me to the approach that you recommend? Let me know if I should post a new question for it.

Comment: @Tim 
FWIW, RedHat adds the lines of text from those `*.jinfo` files into the `/var/lib/alternatives/*` files.  So, maybe that would explain the lack of `update-java-alternatives` explicitly, as it's not needed because `update-alternatives` (as implemented on RHEL) has that already baked in by design.

Comment: @Tim the approach I recommend on Debian & co. is as described in my answer. Feel free to ask another more specific question if you need more details, it’s somewhat beyond the scope of this question IMO!

Comment: Thanks. I created a post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418985/ways-to-configure-alternative-installations-of-oracle-jdk-on-ubuntu