# Ways to configure alternative installations of Oracle JDK on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, jdk

When installing the latest Oracle JDK (8 or 9) on Ubuntu 16.04, I found several discussions:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre/
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/521145/how-to-install-oracle-java-on-ubuntu-14-04
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/159575/how-do-i-make-java-default-to-a-manually-installed-jre-jdk
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/418855/674

I summarize their ways into the following:

- Some use `update-alternatives`. Among them, some use it for `java`, `javac` and `javaws` ([example](https://askubuntu.com/a/55960/1471)), while some use it for more commands (
  [example](https://askubuntu.com/a/68227/1471), [example](https://askubuntu.com/a/159590/1471), [example](https://askubuntu.com/a/846567/1471), [example](https://askubuntu.com/a/822998/1471)). I am not sure which one gives the complete list of commands to apply `update-alternatives` to.
- Some use `update-java-alternatives` ([example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/418855/674), [example](https://askubuntu.com/a/340330/1471), ), but [some says it doesn't work for manual installation](https://askubuntu.com/a/159594/1471).
- Some use both `update-alternatives` and `update-java-alternatives` ([example](https://askubuntu.com/a/68227/1471))
- Some change several environment variables, and think that the previous two approaches are complicated unnecessarily ([example](https://askubuntu.com/a/895024/1471), )
- Some both  use `update-alternatives` and change several environment variables: ([example](https://askubuntu.com/a/521154/1471))
- Some install from ppa:webupd8team/java ([example](https://askubuntu.com/a/61873/1471), [example](https://askubuntu.com/a/99522/1471), [example](https://askubuntu.com/a/295596/1471))

I wonder which way(s) is recommended?

Thanks.

Comment: Any way that works for you.

Comment: I guess Stephen doesn't think so https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/418855/674

Answer (score 5):

When I say that I recommend `update-java-alternatives` for Java alternatives, I’m assuming that whatever Java providers are installed provide the necessary infrastructure. That’s the case for the OpenJDK packages available in Debian and its derivatives, but not necessarily for other JDK packages, and it’s unlikely to be the case for a manually-installed JDK. Oracle JDK packages created using `java-package` *do* provide the necessary infrastructure. I don’t think it’s a sensible use of people’s time to set up the alternatives for all the Java commands manually: if you want to install the Oracle JRE or JDK, use `java-package`.

The point of `update-java-alternatives` is to allow a consistent setup of the default JRE/JDK tools. In theory, this could be done using `update-alternatives`’ `--slave` relationships; however that doesn’t work generally for OpenJDK packages because you can have a subset of the available tools installed, which `update-alternatives` doesn’t deal with. Hence the creation of `update-java-alternatives`, which takes care of whatever tools *are* installed and doesn’t complain about anything else. For `update-java-alternatives` to work though, JRE/JDK packages have to provide the necessary information, in a file in `/usr/lib/jvm` (*e.g.* `.java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64.jinfo`). (`update-alternatives` on RPM-based distributions does cope with this, apparently, but I haven’t looked into the details.)

Java itself has its own way of choosing among multiple installed JREs/JDKs, the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. `update-java-alternatives` and `JAVA_HOME` are really complementary: it should be possible to set both to point at different JREs/JDKs, depending on your requirements. `update-java-alternatives` allows the *system administrator* to specify which JRE/JDK should be the default on a system (in fact, one might consider that it allows the package maintainers to specify which should be the default — it’s all supposed to work transparently for the administrators and users). `JAVA_HOME` allows any user or startup script to specify which JRE/JDK should be used in a specific environment. Where things fall apart somewhat on Unix-style systems is with `PATH`-handling, since `PATH` can’t be set to dynamically use `JAVA_HOME` to choose `java`, `javac` etc. (unlike on Windows); so you need to remember to re-set your `PATH` when you change your `JAVA_HOME`, if you want your default `java` etc. to track your `JAVA_HOME` setting (add `$JAVA_HOME/bin` to the start of your `PATH`).

The take-away from all this is similar to my answer to [Can setting up environment variables replace using `update-alternatives`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/418986/86440): the system administrator should use `update-java-alternatives` to define the default JRE/JDK for the system (or let the packages choose themselves), and users can use `JAVA_HOME` to define the JRE/JDK for a specific environment.