# Switch Java version when starting program

Tags: command-line, java

I have a CentOs machine where Java 8 and Java 11 is installed. Some (command line) programs need Java 8 because they did not moved to Java 11 yet, others need Java 11.

Is there a way to switch Java version before starting a command line program?

Comment: You could set your PATH variable appropriately before starting the program either manually or in a start script.

Comment: @mnille could be simpler to just the specify `/full/path/to/java` in a script.

Answer (score 2):

If you can specify the `java` command to use, in many cases that will be sufficient; for example, using the OpenJDK packages,

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0/bin/java
```

will start the Java 8 VM,

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11/bin/java
```

will start the Java 11 VM.

In some cases, or if you can’t specify the `java` command to use, you’ll also need to set `JAVA_HOME`, to the directory containing `bin` (`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0` or `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11` following the examples above).

Comment: If one is stuck using `/usr/bin/java` note that the _alternatives_ system, if employed, does not respect `JAVA_HOME`.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/419023/5132 for a lot more on this.